# Tensorflow: How to Optimize the Prediction on GCloud-ML?

Tags: tensorflow, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I have a model published on GCloud-ML and it is working fine. I can do the Online predicitons and get the right results. My issue is the Performance. Each predict (inference) takes around 3.5 seconds and it is not good for my case. I'm using automatically scale and my bucket is US-Central. My images have around 100Kb and I'm in Brazil (in the GCloud Console I can see tha latency --> 1.5 seconds).
I already tried the optimazed_for_inference.py but it didn't work (I can't generate the saved_model from the optimazed graph. It is possible?).

I need to get the result at least in 2 seconds. My doubt is: Is it possible to do that? 
or is it normal to get results in 3 / 4 seconds using gcloud-ml predict?

Thanks! Any ideas are well coming! If you need more information to help me, please add a comment!
Thanks again!

Comment: When you say GCloud console do you mean `console.google.com` or do you mean `gcloud ml-engine predict`? Second question: How are you sending traffic and measuring the end-to-end latency? Third question: will all of your traffic come from Brazil, or do you have a frontend / backend also in us-central?

Comment: Gcloud console: https://console.cloud.google.com/ . The latency of 1.5 seconds I get in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard ( Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine information). And yes, My servers stay in Brazil and I send the image from here directitly to ml-engine. Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm trying to understand the discrepancy between 1.5 seconds and 3-4 seconds. In our experience, image models take 1.5.2.5 seconds per prediction; the rest of the latency is client side (from client to server and vice-verse). How are you measuring the 3-4 seconds, which seems higher than expected if the prediction itself is taking 1.5 seconds.

Comment: I built a test code and I put a getTime before and after the predict.  So, my total latency is 3-4 seconds and, with your explanation, I believe that the predict is taking 1.5 seconds (the latency I see in gcloud console), but problably i'm taking 2-3 seconds to send the request and get the response.

Comment: If you send me your project/model/version info as well as the timestamps of a few requests (preferably spaced apart by a few seconds), I can check what we're seeing on our side. cloudml-feedback@google.com

Comment: thanks a lot for the help! I'll send the information to you!